# Is a function continous if there are always exactly two points located within radius $r$ if $r$ is a sufficently small real number?

Tags: continuity, real-numbers

#### Intro

It seems to me like a function should be continuous if and only if, for any point on the function $x$ and all very small distances $d$, there are exactly two points on the function which are distance $d$ away from point $x$. Is that true?

---

#### Defintion of Kontinous

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } \forall S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$,
  we say that $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is "***kontinous***"
       if and only if
  $\forall r \in \{r^\prime\in\mathbb{R}:r^\prime>0\}$,
    For any $x \in S \quad$
          $\exists\,\, y \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \text{ and } \exists y^\prime \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \text{ such that } $
                $y \neq y^\prime$
                  $\text{ and }$
              $\forall z \in \mathbb{R}^n, \lvert z- x \rvert = r \text{ if and only if } z \in \{y, y^\prime\}$

#### Conjecture

For any function $f$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ we conjecture that $f$  is a [continuous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition)  if and only if the set $\{\,\,(x, f(x)) \colon \quad x \in \mathbb{R}\,\,\}$ is ***kontinous***

---

#### Note

One difference between ***kontinuity*** and ***continuity*** is outputlined as follows:

- defintions of ***continuity*** often look at *everything* close to a point on the function
- ***kontinuity*** does not look at *everything* close to a point on the function. Only things exactly radius $r$ away, not every radius between zero and $r$.

---

#### Failed Counter-Example

I tried to cook up a counter-example, but it did not work.

$\mathbb{Q}$ denotes the set of all rational numbers $\{a/b: a, b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Let $S = \{(x, x): x \in \mathbb{Q}\} \cup \{(y, -y): y \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}\}$

$f(x) =  
\begin{cases} 
+x & \text{ if } x \text{ is rational} \\
-x & \text{ if } x \text{ is irrational} \\
\end{cases}$

Some Remarks:

- Function $f$ is discontinuous.
- For all small positive distance $d$, there are exactly two points on function $f$ which are distance $d$ away from $(0, 0)$.
- However, is it not true that that for **any** point $x$, there are exactly two points on the function which are distance $d$ away from $x$.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  If $z\in \mathbb R\times \mathbb R$ and $x\in \mathbb R^n$, what does $|z-x|$ mean?

Comment: I think the function $x\sin \frac{1}{x^2}$ (with $f(0)=0)$ is a counterexample that is continuous everywhere.

Comment: @lulu I made a mistake. I meant to write $z \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ not $z \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$